# Stop airbrake from filtering HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header

Tags: ruby, sinatra, airbrake

In our Sinatra app we use Airbrake. By default, Airbrake is configured to filter out sensitive params like HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header, but I would like to remove that filtration.

I followed the "[Filtering or Ignoring data before it's sent to Airbrake](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/wiki/Filtering-or-ignoring-data-before-it's-sent-to-Airbrake#filter-out-sensitive-data-from-params)" wiki, where it mentioned following:

```
Airbrake.configure do |config|
  config.api_key      = '1234567890abcdef'
  config.params_filters << "credit_card_number"
end
```

I tried to see what `params_filter` contains:

```
Airbrake.configure do |config|
  config.api_key      = '1234567890abcdef'
  config.params_filters.each {|param| puts "filter name: #{param}"}
end
```

The output I got was:

```
filter name: password
filter name: password_confirmation
```

As you can see, there is no mention of HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header.

Can anyone tell me how do I log HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header in Airbrake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been fixed by newer interface of airbrake